How do we confirm if a record is referenced every time a related record is viewed
As per Salesforce documentation for For View and For Reference Keywords in SOQL,

'A record is referenced every time a related record is viewed. For
example, when a user views an account record, all related records
(such as contacts, owner, leads, opportunities) are referenced.'

Does this mean that when i view an account record, 'LastReferencedDate' field on all related records also gets updated?
I tried this scenario by opening the record and checking the LastReferencedDate, and see that there is no change. EVen tried with querying Account record with For View keyword, still related records 'LastReferencedDate' remained unchanged. Can someone tell what does reference means in this context?

